# Compact generation of a single list with multiple list multiplication operators

Tags: python

I want to generate a bit list with a pattern, the code is like this:

```
sublist = [1] * N_SUBBITS
sublist[0]  = 0 
bits = sublist * N_SUBLISTS
```

If `N_SUBBITS = 4` and `N_SUBLISTS = 3`, this generates lists like this:

```
[0, 1, 1 ,1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Is it possible to write this with a single expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> N_SUBBITS = 4
>>> N_SUBLISTS = 3
>>> ([0] + [1]*(N_SUBBITS-1)) * N_SUBLISTS
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is as concise as I need

Answer (score 3):

Will this do?

```
In [4]: [1 if x % N_SUBBITS else 0 for x in range(N_SUBBITS * N_SUBLISTS)]
Out[4]: [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Another one:

```
In [15]: [1 if x else 0 for l in range(N_SUBLISTS) for x in range(N_SUBBITS)]
Out[15]: [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Variations:

```
[x % N_SUBBITS and 1 for x in range(N_SUBBITS * N_SUBLISTS)]
[x and 1 for l in range(N_SUBLISTS) for x in range(N_SUBBITS)]
```